# How to use .mod files with ifort

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to use a module from a .mod file, however I can't make the compiler find it:

**teste1.f90**

```
module teste_modu

  public :: testePrint

contains

  subroutine testePrint()
    print *, ".mod works"
  end subroutine testePrint

end module teste_modu
```

**teste2.f90**

```
program teste

  use teste_modu


  call testePrint()

end program teste
```

I used this command to get the .mod

```
$ ifort -c teste1.f90
```

It outputs teste_modu.mod. Then I try to compile using

```
$ ifort -I/home/ricardo/Code/hdf5/ teste2.f90
/tmp/ifortid0I4q.o: In function `MAIN__':
teste2.f90:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `teste_modu_mp_testeprint_'
```

How can I compile teste2.f90 using the content of teste_modu.mod?

Comment: Check [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/694273).

Comment: I made the trial above after reading this document. I just can't make it work

Comment: Yes, the duplicated solved my problem. The .o files are also required.

Comment: You can also take a look here for a full sample of Fortran based project with modules, Makefile, subdirectories, etc.: http://www.owsiak.org/fortran-and-gnu-make/